# Amplify DAC output

Tags: amplifier, transformer, stm32, dac

I am using a STM32L053 to generate a sin wave with the DAC output. The voltage range is from 0V - 3.3V with a frequency of 40kHz. Because i have to run the Piezo with a higher voltage, i need to amplify my amplitude. The device is powered my a Battery with 4.2V, so i can't use a simple OP amplifier. My idea was to put a SMD Transformer with a turns ratio of 1:3.5 on the PCB attached to my DAC. Is this possible and are there any reference schematics for that problem?

Comment: 1) the output of the DAC for sure cannot drive the transformer with enough power so you'll need an amplifier anyway 2) Most Opamps have an output that isn't much stronger than the DAC's output. 3) What is the actual voltage you need on the Piezo element? 4) I think your best bet would be to use an audio amplifier, audio is only up to 20 kHz but many amplifiers can handle much more than that.

Comment: I need about 12V to make the Piezo swing. I found this transformer [link](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/192/GT17005-1588915.pdf). So i should use an adio amplifier in front of the transformer?

Comment: I'd start with a 12v battery and regulate that down to 3.3v for the DAC. Then consider ways to drive the piezo with 12v (perhaps an "[H-bridge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270839/understand-h-bridge)" circuit.)

Comment: I think the transformer is only borderline compatible with your requirements.

Comment: Maybe i should use a DC-DC converter to generate +/- 12V power supply and use this Voltage to Amplify the the output Voltage of my DAC with an OP amp?