# Maglev Train Propulsion System

Tags: electromagnetism, polarity

So I'm trying to make a small Maglev train for a science fair project. I understand how to make the train levitate, but not how to make it move forward. When I look online, everyone explains how you can have magnets on the sides of the track and magnets on the sides of the train: [image: Image of walls of the track and the train.]

To make the train continuously move forward, you must constantly alternate the polarity of the electromagnets, but I don't know how to do that. Is there some kind of tool that can automatically convert the polarity of the magnet? 
Last thing: is there a reason why the magnets on the sides of the train are not in the same position?

Please help.

Comment: Way too broad. There is some kind of chip that ... with years of study and experiment can be made to do what you want ... but an answer would be a book in the region of a thousand pages.

Comment: What @BrianDrummond says is true, but if you look closely at the picture you provided, you'll notice some arrows and a text saying "*Note the changing of polarity in position*". That's a hint that the magnets on the margin can switch polarity, thus they are controlled, and the speed with which they do so is a function of the train's speed. The same polarity change, but reversed, is applied when breaking.

Comment: How long will your track be?

Comment: I said chip as a suggestion. Does anyone know how the engineers did it in the real maglev trains?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I'm not sure but it's probably going to be about a meter in the shape of an oval.

Answer (score 1):

Each electromagnet has an H-bridge circuit. Reverses polarity the same way a brushed motor reverses direction.

[Understand H-Bridge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270839/understand-h-bridge)

All the circuits are coordinated with a processor or something like that. Find a more manual route for a science fair project. You probably don't have enough time or money to learn and build a processor controlled version of anything.

Are your electromagnets on the track or train?

If on the track, you are going to need a LOT of relays wired up as H-bridges. Four SPST relays or two DPDT relays per electromagnet. Definitely not enough time to build a loop this way even if you had 100% of the knowledge already required. If this is what you plan then demonstrate just a short linear section. I don't think you can afford the money or time for all the relays for a full loop.

If on the train, you could use permanent magnets for the track and put the electromagnets on the train. Less parts but your train is heavier and harder to move. You could use hall switches to detect the permanent magnets to decide when to switch the electromagnets, but you definitely need to get help, in person, from an adult who already knows electronics since circuit design and soldering will be involved. Alternatively draw black/white marks under the track that the train views to tell the train when to switch polarities. Might be easier since this is more similar to the simplest line following robot designs which you can copy. You could do this without a processor involves a more complicated circuit, but it might be a bit easier with a processor if you pick one super, super easy to learn like a PICAXE or Arduino.

I used to judge science fairs and having anything functional that works properly is impressive. Even manual switches that you flip in the proper sequence to inch the train along would impress.

Comment: thanks so much. Do you know about Inductracks? How exactly do they work? Because I can't wrap my head around how having a Haibach Array under the train and copper wires in the track can make the train float AND move.

Comment: @AnthonyZong I only know what the Wikipedia entry says. It does not sound like the Inductrack makes it move. It sounds like it only makes it levitate *while* it moves under the power of something else. Permanent magnets on the train are arranged in a Halbach array and when they are quickly moved past the coils, a current is generated in the coils that produces a magnetic field which opposes the permanet magnets and levitates the train. It is speed dependent so you have to be moving fast enough.

Comment: @AnthonyZong So it is magnetically analogous to how airplanes work. Airplanes stay aloft in the air the same way a stone doesn't sink by skipping on water. This is the same thing but with magnets. I think there is a different mechanism that makes it move but I do not think it involves the PM halbach array

Comment: Do the copper coils on the track have to have an electrical current flowing through them? Also I think the coils need to be positioned a specific way on the track.

Comment: @AnthonyZong The coils do have current flowing in them, but they do not have current being pumped into them (i.e. not connected to a power supply). The current is being induced in the coils by the permanent magnets moving along with the train car. The same way a generator produces current by moving magnets and conductors relative to each other. The coils alignment does matter with respect to the movement of the magnets.

Comment: Thank you. I believe the coils need to be in like a ladder shape and the edges of the coils need to be "shorted". What does "shorted" mean and why ladder?

Comment: @AnthonyZong Shorted means there is a low-resistance connection (a shortcut for the electrons, if you will, so the current avoids running through other parts of the circuit) across whatever you are talking about. In this case, the coil. Which just makes a it a loop of wire. No power supply connections. When you short-circuit a battery, you are connecting a low-resistance connection straight across the battery terminals.

Comment: Oooh thank you so much for all your help. I think I'll try to design my Inductrack now.